# Code coverage for jinja2 templates in Django

Tags: python, django, code-coverage, jinja2, coverage.py

Following Ned Batchelder's [Coverage.py for Django templates](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201501/coveragepy_for_django_templates.html) blog post and the [django_coverage_plugin](https://github.com/nedbat/django_coverage_plugin) plugin for measuring code coverage of Django templates.

I would really like to see template coverage reports, but the problem is - we have replaced the Django's the template engine with `jinja2` through the [`coffin` adapter](https://github.com/coffin/coffin/). I know it is not recommended, but we had reasons. Basically, instead of Django's `render_to_response()` we are using:

```
from coffin.shortcuts import render_to_response
```

Currently, we are using [`django-coverage`](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage)'s [`test_coverage` command](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage/src/f99189abb55e/django_coverage/management/commands/?at=test_coverage) to run tests with coverage:

```
python manage.py test_coverage project_name
```

I understand that the setup is not common. But, is it possible to gather code coverage metrics for `jinja2` templates with coverage.py? If not, I would appreciate any ideas on making a plugin similar to `django_coverage_plugin`, but for `jinja2`.

Comment: why would you ask here instead of sending me an email like I mentioned in the blog post? :)

Comment: @NedBatchelder cause I know you are around and would notice the post :) Besides this might be useful for others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plugin support in coverage.py is still in an alpha state.  I've implemented the Django template support and half of the Mako support.  A Jinja plugin would be appreciated.  It might need changes in Jinja to make it feasible, in particular, to map the compiled Python code execution back to template line numbers.

If you want to start work on it, read the interfaces in plugin.py in the coverage.py source (I'll eventually write real docs, of course).  The source for the Mako plugin might help also: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coverage-mako-plugin

This will likely involve us working together to get past the rough parts.  Drop me an email! :)

Thanks for taking it on!

Updated: I've written some docs for the plugins, though more are needed: http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0a4/plugins.html